# Nonlinear ODE $a^2u''+bu'+b^*(u')^2/u+cu=-1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

Consider the ODE
$$[a(x)]^2u''+b(x)u'+b^*(x)(u')^2/u+c(x)u=-1$$
on $\mathbb{R}$. I am trying to make it looks better by writing it as a variational problem ($u$ is some minimizer of some energy functionals). Do anyone have ideas about that? Or any good change of variable to reduce the nonlinearity of the equation? My only thought is to write $u=e^v$ and
$$[a(x)]^2v''+b(x)v'+\{b^*(x)+[a(x)]^2\}(v')^2+c(x)=-e^{-v},$$
but I do not know if it is useful.

Comment: Your equations of motion are dissipative, that is why you may need one of the techniques exposed at https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Classical_Mechanics/Variational_Principles_in_Classical_Mechanics_(Cline)/10%3A_Nonconservative_Systems/10.05%3A_Dissipative_Lagrangians

Comment: @Abezhiko Can you be more specific? I cannot relate my equation to the link you mentioned.